Semiperfect modules are $D1$
Let $M_R$ be a module. We say that $M$ is lifting or has $D1$ if for every submodule $N \subset M$ there is a decomposition $M=A \oplus B$ such that $A \subset N$ and $N \cap B \ll M$ (that is, $N \cap B$ is a small submodule of $M$).
By a projective cover of $M$ we mean a projective module $P$ and an epimorphism $f:P\to M$ with $\ker f \ll P$.
We say that $M$ is semiperfect if $M$ is projective and every homomorphic image of $M$ has a projective cover.
How can I give a proof of the fact that $M$ is semiperfect $\Longrightarrow$ $M$ has $D1$.

A module over what?

Over any ring..
